# PHP, is it possible and if it is a simple process, how to overwrite the dollar sign, $?

Tags: php, overwrite

I was wondering if it's possible to overwrite the dollar sign in php (the one that prefixes variable names, like `$var`). I am wondering if I can overwrite it to something like the pound sign (£), a Chinese symbol, or perhaps the number sign (#), for `£var`, `木var`, or `#var`.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Even if this was possible, you would risk that not a single existing script out there would work anymore, as all rely on basic concepts like "a variable is preceeded by $" - on the other side, what would be the benefit?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: It was a curiosity of mine, seemed to be a fun thing to do, and if it was possible in a simple way, it would be good to learn. I updated the question so it's not just is it possible, but also includes possibly how.

Answer (score 4):

You certainly could. You would need to download the PHP source, and modify the parser to support this instead. Not trivial, but a possibility due to the fact that PHP is open source.